# React Router and Arbitrary Query Params: Page Refreshes Unintentionally on Load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-string, react-router

I've been using React Router with great success the past few weeks, but I just ran into an issue that I can't seem to find a resolution for.  Whenever an arbitrary query parameter is appended to a url (in our case, for URL tracking purposes from email) the page that you land on will load, then automatically refresh without warning.

Given the most basic of route setups:

```
var routes = (
  <Route handler={ResultsController}>
     <DefaultRoute handler={Results} />
  </Route>
);
```

And a default handler:

```
Router.run(routes, function (Handler, state) {
  React.render(<Handler params={state.params} />, domElement);
});
```

If I navigate to `http://whatever.com/results` everything works as it should, but if I navigate to `http://whatever.com/results?ref=track` the page will refresh and redirect back to `http://whatever.com/results#/`.  Please note that appending queryParams *after* the hash and slash results in correct behavior; problem is, many of these links are generated server-side and forcing hashes in such a way is not desired.

Do I need to setup a wildcard handler for queryParams?  Any pointers to documentation would be helpful as well.

Edit:
While this doesn't address the overarching question / bug leading to unintentional refreshes, I've found that loading the route using the Router.HistoryLocation PushState option allows for queryParams pre-render:

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler, state) {
  React.render(<Handler params={state.params} query={state.query} />, domElement);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using `Router.HashLocation`, the default location if you don't specify one.

`Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(...`

Will fix the problem, but you'll need a server that can handle it.

If you still want hash location, put your query *after* the `#`. As far as `HashLocation` is concerned, the query before the `#` is not part of the location that it understands.

Comment: Thank you; this sufficiently answers my question.