# react-router does not maintain query params and calls onEnter twice

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a small app where I want users to be able to add a token to an URL, so the can share these urls around (similar to this [use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208655/how-to-deal-with-query-params-in-react-react-router-flux).

In order to do that, they have a form where they can submit these credentials, and then it navigates to another route by using `this.context.router.push`.

This route has an onEnter handler, which will initialize an API client with these credentials, make an async call to make sure they work, and then store an instance of that client so that it wouldn't need to be reinitialized on subsequent onEnter calls.

What happens is that before the async call even finishes, a page refresh happens, and the querystring parameters will be gone. This means onEnter gets called again, without those same querystring parameters.

However, and here it gets interesting, if I just navigate to say http://localhost:9020/page?qsparam=paramvalue the refresh doesn't happen and the parameter is maintained.

I've created a simpler version of my app, with everything that doesn't matter removed, which still demonstrates the issue. You can find it at https://github.com/contentful/discovery-app-react/tree/react-router

The important bits are:
- The push call: https://github.com/contentful/discovery-app-react/blob/react-router/src/main.js#L11
- The routes declaration https://github.com/contentful/discovery-app-react/blob/react-router/src/main.js#L39
- The requireCredentials method, used for the onEnter handler https://github.com/contentful/discovery-app-react/blob/react-router/src/main.js#L47

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is kind of ridiculous and obvious but essentially the problem here is that I'm missing an event.preventDefault on the form handler.

I blame myself for not being that used to work with React itself and expecting it for somehow handling it magically.